# What is the source for the battle between Leviathan and Behemoth in the end of days?

Tags: agada-stories-legends, behemoth, leviathan

I hear often the tradition that the Leviathan and the Behemoth will engage in battle and kill each other in the end of days. I was wondering what is the (earliest) source for this tradition?

**EDIT**

On a wikipedia page I found this

> A Jewish rabbinic legend describes a great battle which will take place between them at the end of time: "they will interlock with one another and engage in combat, with his horns the Behemoth will gore with strength, the fish [Leviathan] will leap to meet him with his fins, with power. Their Creator will approach them with his mighty sword [and slay them both];" then, "from the beautiful skin of the Leviathan, God will construct canopies to shelter the righteous, who will eat the meat of the Behemoth and the Leviathan amid great joy and merriment."

But the quote is not sourced.

I did some Googling and found that the first part of the quote comes from Akdamut. Akdamut is only about a 1,000 years old though. Where did Rabbi Meir bar Yitzchak get this from?

Comment: @שלום I have edited my question. I'm looking for something that is as specific as the unsourced quote I found.

Answer (score 3):

The battle mentioned in the Tanchuma is alluded to in a more terse form in **Vayikra Rabba 13** (Parshas Shemini)

> כֵּיצַד הֵם נִשְׁחָטִים? בְּהֵמוֹת נוֹתֵץ לַלִּוְיָתָן
> בְּקַרְנָיו וְקוֹרְעוֹ, וְלִוְיָתָן נוֹתֵץ לַבְּהֵמוֹת בִּסְנַפִּירָיו
> וְנוֹחֲרוֹ.

It explains how each will jointly meet their end.  The Behemoth will kill the Leviathan with its horns at the same time as the Leviathan will kill the Behemoth with its fins.

Answer (score 2):

The Medrash Tanchuma mentions their battle in parshas Shemini #7.

מה אכפת לו להקדוש ברוך הוא שיאכלו ישראל בלא שחיטה, שיהא ישראל נוחר ואוכל ושוחט מן הצואר מן הירך. תדע, שלא נצטוה השחיטה הזו אלא כדי לצרף את ישראל, כי לעתיד לבא עושה סעודה לצדיקים מן הבהמה ולויתן ואין שם שחיטה. תדע לך, לויתן בריה משונה הוא, והמלאכים יגורו ממנו, שנאמר, משאתו יגורו אלים (איוב מא יז). ואם הם זורקין עליו כמה רמחים של ברזל, כתבן הוא חושבן, שנאמר, יחשוב לתבן ברזל (שם שם יט). וכן בהמות שדי קשה, שהוא רובץ על אלף הרים, שנאמר, בהמות בהררי אלף (תה' נ י). והיכן הן נשחטין. אלא זה לזה מזדווגין שניהם, שנאמר, אחד באחד יגשו (איוב מא ח). בהמות יגש בלויתן ואוחז בקרניו ובוקע. ולויתן הפך יהיה מיתתו, שמכה אותו בזנבו והורגו, והצדיקים הולכין ונוטלין מנות מנות. מכאן שחיטה. אלא בשביל לבדוק ולצרף את ישראל: